# Actualizar macro en Zendesk via API con Python

Tags: python, api, macros

Os escribo para ver si en vuestra sabiduría podéis ayudarme en algo que realmente me ahorraría muchas horas de trabajo.

Necesito actualizar unas macros que tenemos creadas en Zendesk añadiéndoles un campo más adicional al que ya tienen. Para ello tendría que hacer un GET, obtener los datos de la macro, y después un PUT con esos datos + el campo nuevo.

La parte del GET la he conseguido pero al intentar hacer el PUT siempre me da error 400, me temo que pueda ser algo acerca de cómo he escrito la petición pero sinceramente recién estoy aprendiendo y estoy bastante perdida.

Os dejo el código a ver si me podéis echar una mano:

```
## PETICIÓN GET

url = "https://XXXXXX.zendesk.com/api/v2/macros/360033417100.json"
response = requests.get(url, auth=(username + "/token", token))

content = response.content
macro_json = json.loads(content)
dict(macro_json)


titulo = macro_json['macro']['title']
acciones = macro_json['macro']['actions']
restricciones = macro_json['macro']['restriction']


## AÑADO LA NUEVA VARIABLE TAG_0004
var = acciones.append({'field': 'custom_fields_360008721299', 'value': 'tag_0004'})

## CREO EL CUERPO DE LA PETICIÓN
payload = "{'macro':{'title': '" + str(titulo) + "', 'actions': " + str(acciones) + "}}"

### HAGO EL PUT
actualizacion = requests.put(url, auth=(username + "/token", token), data=payload)
respuesta = actualizacion.content
print(actualizacion)
print(actualizacion.response)
print(respuesta)
```

En la documentación de Zendesk sobre las [macros](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/support/macros#update-many-macros) dan ejemplos de cómo hacerlo con cURL pero debería poderse hacer igualmente con python no? He hecho alguna petición con Postman y ha funcionado así escrita pero para este caso no me vale porque para añadir un campo tendría que coger todos los anteriores y sumarle el nuevo y con postman sería muy manual.

Cualquier sugerencia será bienvenida, muchísimas gracias.

Comment: Me respondo sola porque finalmente he logrado solucionarlo leyendo una respuesta en el sitio inglés:

Lo que hay que hacer es no codificar la data y ponerla tal que así: data={'macro': {'actions': updated_data}}, restando un nivel de comillas.